# Computed column with less size than the "referring column"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index

I have a column with data type `nvarchar(max)` and I wold like to index this. However, since it's too big it's not possible. So I figured I could create a persisted computed column based on that column with the formula:

```
left(isnull([fieldValue],''),500)
```

However this column also gets a data type of `nvarchar(max)` so I can't create an index for it. Is it possible to index it somehow without using a full-text index?

Comment: An index on CHECKSUM(YourColumn) might better fit your needs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just do a simple cast in your computed column:

```
create table YourTable
(
    -- your other columns....
    YourCompCol as cast(left(isnull(fieldValue, ''), 500) as nvarchar(500))
)
go

create index IX_CompCol
on YourTable(YourCompCol)
go
```

### Nota Bene

*The maximum key length is 900 bytes, and nvarchar(500) has a maximum length of 1000 bytes.  In other words, an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE` could potentially fail.*

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to index any more than 900 bytes, so with `NVARCHAR`, that means the first 450 characters. The important point is that using `LEFT` on its own does not set the destination data type, you need to do that explicitly using `CAST` or `CONVERT`, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Whatever ADD ComputedColumnName 
  AS CONVERT(NVARCHAR(450), COALESCE([fieldValue],'')) PERSISTED;
```

Comment: Why `persisted`?

Comment: @MartinSmith It sounded like the purpose was to index it. I don't recall ever wanting to index a computed column but not persist it. Also, the OP specifically said they wanted it persisted. Why would I NOT want to persist it in this case?

Comment: `persisted` is not a requirement to index it and it will just bloat the data page IMO by increasing the length of each row by up to 900 bytes.

Comment: @MartinSmith noted.